# Access MySQL server on Guest machine from another guest Vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant

How can I access a MySQL server running on a Vagrant guest machine from another guest machine?

Comment: please, could you explain a little more the problem do you want to solved?

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was to do with the Vagrant network configuration, it was in fact to do with the MySQL users permissions!

Comment: can you share your config?